# Fill up the missing column within group

Tags: r

I received a excel file like this:

```
structure(list(`Variable Name` = c("form.hhConsent", NA, NA, 
"form.hhReasonRefused", NA, NA, NA, "form.childrenRepeat.childrenGroup.childSex", 
NA, NA, "form.childrenRepeat.childrenGroup.dobSourceWho", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "form.hohSex", NA, NA, "form.mothersRepeat.mothersGroup.spouseSex", 
NA, NA, "form.childrenRepeat.childrenGroup.treatmentConsent", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "form.childrenRepeat.childrenGroup.noTreatReason", 
NA, NA, NA), Type = c(NA, "1", "0", NA, "1", "2", "99", NA, "1", 
"2", NA, "1", "2", "3", "99", NA, "1", "2", NA, "1", "2", NA, 
"1", "0", "2", "3", NA, "1", "2", "99"), Meaning = c(NA, "Yes", 
"No", NA, "No responsible could be found", "They don't want to", 
"Other reason", NA, "Male", "Female", NA, "Mother", "Father", 
"Neighbor", "Others", NA, "Male", "Female", NA, "Male", "Female", 
NA, "Yes", "No", "AMR grappe", "M54 grappe", NA, "allergy", "parent refusal", 
"other"), Missing_values = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Format_values = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

The current file looks like:

```
variable name   type      meaning
X1
                xxx         xxx
                xxx         xxx     
X2
                xxx.        xxx
                xxx         xxx
                xxx         xxx
x3
                xxx         xxx
```

I want to convert it as regular dataset, which looks like:

```
variable name   type   meaning
x1               xxx.   xxx
x1               xxx.   xxx
x2               xxx    xxx
x2               xxx.   xxx
x2               xxx.   xxx
x3               xxx.   xxx
```

My thought is: first group by "variable name", and then filling up the missing variable name, the last step is filter out the head row without any value in col of type and meaning. But it does not work. The issue is that there is no var can be group_by.

Could someone help to figure out how to make it in R? Thanks a lot~~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `fill` (from `tidyr`) to replace the NA elements in the 'Variable Name' with the previous non-NA, then `select` the first three columns, and use `filter` with `if_all` to keep only rows having all non-NA elements in the 'Type', 'Meaning' columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  fill(`Variable Name`) %>%
  select(1:3) %>% 
  filter(if_all(Type:Meaning, complete.cases))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 22 × 3
   `Variable Name`                                Type  Meaning                      
   <chr>                                          <chr> <chr>                        
 1 form.hhConsent                                 1     Yes                          
 2 form.hhConsent                                 0     No                           
 3 form.hhReasonRefused                           1     No responsible could be found
 4 form.hhReasonRefused                           2     They don't want to           
 5 form.hhReasonRefused                           99    Other reason                 
 6 form.childrenRepeat.childrenGroup.childSex     1     Male                         
 7 form.childrenRepeat.childrenGroup.childSex     2     Female                       
 8 form.childrenRepeat.childrenGroup.dobSourceWho 1     Mother                       
 9 form.childrenRepeat.childrenGroup.dobSourceWho 2     Father                       
10 form.childrenRepeat.childrenGroup.dobSourceWho 3     Neighbor                     
# … with 12 more rows
```

EDIT: Based on @Leon Samson's comments

Comment: I think this will also work without the `group_by` and `ungroup`, which would make it easier.

Comment: @LeonSamson you are right.  I was kind of confused with the description about the grouping

Comment: Nice edit. Furthermore, just another suggestion/option which is more based on preference I think: you can also replace the entire filter statement with `na.omit()` in this specific case.

Comment: @LeonSamson that was my first solution, but later I replaced with `if_all` as `na.omit` can remove the row if there is any NAs, whereas this can only remove NAs if both columns have non-NA (the OP's example does work with na.omit as well, but I was thinking that their orignal data may have some cases)